# Log4J Rolling Log Give Access To Windows "Everyone"

Tags: java, windows-7, permissions, log4j

I'm using log4j to do a daily rolling log.

I'm trying to find a way to set permissions on the new log files, when they are created, which would give read and write access to "Everyone".

This program will only be ran on Win7 and WinXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, newly created fies inherit permissions from the directory they're in. Just create a new directory for these files with the appropriate permissions on it and the file will inherit.